# Why do i get this wrong result?

Tags: c++

I'M trying to make a code that is able to increase int 'd' by one each time the a+b reach 20.

and if there still any number less than 20 then this will be the int 'c'.

but instead of getting the right result in my next program which is

```
49-0
```

i get this wrong answer

```
47-40
```

what should i do ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a=50;
    int b=18;
    int c=a+b;
    int d=0;
    int i;
for(i=0;i<c;i++)
   {
    while(c>20)
   {
     d+=1;
     c=c-20;
     break;
   }}
    cout<<d<<"-"<<c;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your while loop:

```
while(c > 20)
{
  d+=1;
  c=c-20;
  break;
}
```

The loop will only execute once because of your break statement.

Comment: When i removed the break statement it gave me 48-20 while the right answer is 49-0

Comment: You probably want `while(c >= 20)`